# How can i get all combination of symbols(how to iterate this arrays)?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this symbols arraylist

```
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Letter>> setLetters() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Letter>> letters = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Letter> letter = new ArrayList<>();

    letter.add(new Letter('r', 0, 0));
    letter.add(new Letter('r', 1, 6));
    letter.add(new Letter('r', 3, 9));
    letters.add(letter);

    letter = new ArrayList<>();
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 4, 1));
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 4, 3));
    letters.add(letter);

    letter = new ArrayList<>();
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 4, 6));
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 4, 7));
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 5, 1));
    letters.add(letter);

    letter = new ArrayList<>();
    letter.add(new Letter('o', 5, 4));
    letters.add(letter);

    letter = new ArrayList<>();
    letter.add(new Letter('r', 5, 5));
    letter.add(new Letter('r', 5, 9));
    letters.add(letter);

    letter = new ArrayList<>();
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 6, 2));
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 8, 2));
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 8, 3));
    letters.add(letter);

    letter = new ArrayList<>();
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 6, 5));
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 6, 7));
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 6, 8));
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 7, 3));
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 7, 8));
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 9, 2));
    letter.add(new Letter('e', 9, 3));
    letters.add(letter);

    letter = new ArrayList<>();
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 7, 1));
    letter.add(new Letter('s', 9, 4));
    letters.add(letter);

 return letters;
}
```

How can I get all 1512 combination of symbols, in ArrayList like
this:

> r{0,0}e{4,1}s{4,6}o{5,4}r{5,5}s{6,2}e{6,5}s{7,1} ; 
>   r{0,0}e{4,1}s{4,6}o{5,4}r{5,5}s{6,2}e{6,5}s{9,4} ; ....

another 1510 combinations

Idk how to iterate this Arrays ><

Comment: Show some progress first. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Please read [How to Ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and update your question with the code you have tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details of the exact problem so we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the number of permutations (in your case 1510 - multiply the sizes of all the individual sets together).

Then for each iteration index, you just do a modulo arithmetic to append an item out of each set, and then divide by that same set size before picking the next item out of the set.

Something like this:

```
long permutations = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < letter.size(); i++)
{
    int setcount = letter[i].size();
    if (setcount == 0)
    {
       continue;
    }
    permutations *= setcount;
}

for (long p = 0; p < permutations; p++)
{
    long index = p;
    String s = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < letter.size(); i++)
    {
        if (letter[i].size() > 0)
        {
            ArrayList<Letter> innerIndex = index % letter[i].size();
            index /= letter[i].size();

            // append letter[i].get(innerIndex) to s, then append a semi-colon 
        }
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive algorithm:

```
public static void generateCombinations(
        List<List<Letter>> letters, Consumer<List<Letter>> handler) {
    List<List<Letter>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
    addCombinations(letters, new ArrayList<>(), handler);
}

private static void addCombinations(List<List<Letter>> letters,
        List<Letter> current, Consumer<List<Letter>> handler) {
    int currentIndex = current.size();
    if (currentIndex >= letters.size()) {
        handler.accept(new ArrayList<>(current));
    } else {
        for (Letter letter: letters.get(currentIndex)) {
            current.add(letter);
            addCombinations(letters, current, handler);
            current.remove(currentIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
List<List<Letter>> letters = setLetters();
generateCombinations(letters, list -> System.out.println(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively without having to evaluate first the number of combinations:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Letter>> combinations(ArrayList<ArrayList<Letter>> source, int step, ArrayList<ArrayList<Letter>> currentCombinations) {

    if( step == 0 ) {
        // init first pass because there are no current combinations.
        ArrayList<Letter> lettersAtStep = source.get(step);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Letter>> nextCombinations = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Letter l : lettersAtStep) {
            ArrayList<Letter> firstLetter = new ArrayList<>();
            firstLetter.add(l);
            nextCombinations.add(firstLetter);
        }
        return combinations(source, step+1, nextCombinations);
    }
    else if( step == source.size() ) {
        // No more letters to add.
        return currentCombinations;
    }

    ArrayList<Letter> lettersAtStep = source.get(step);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Letter>> nextCombinations = new ArrayList<>();

    for( ArrayList<Letter> comb : currentCombinations) {
        for (Letter l : lettersAtStep) {
            // Add each new Letter to each existing combination.
            ArrayList<Letter> item = new ArrayList(comb);
            item.add(l);
            nextCombinations.add(item);
        }
    }

    return combinations(source, step+1, nextCombinations);
}
```

Then, you call it:

```
 combinations(setLetters(), 0, new ArrayList<>());
```

It returns you all the combinations in an ArrayList as attended.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an `Iterator`.

```
public <T> Iterator<List<T>> combinations(final List<List<T>> lists) {
    return new Iterator<List<T>>() {
        // One index for each list.
        int[] index = new int[lists.size()];
        boolean justStarted = true;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // We've finished when all the indexes are back at zero.
            if (justStarted) {
                justStarted = false;
                return true;
            }
            // Any of them non-zero?
            for (int i : index) {
                if (i != 0) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> next() {
            List<T> next = new ArrayList<>(lists.size());
            // Make the current one.
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
                next.add(i, lists.get(i).get(index[i]));
            }
            // Take one step.
            for (int i = lists.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                // Step on one list.
                if (++index[i] < lists.get(i).size()) break;
                // List exhausted - reset it to zero.
                index[i] = 0;
            }
            return next;
        }
    };

}

class Letter {
    private final char c;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Letter(char c, int x, int y) {
        this.c = c;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return c + "{" + x + "," + y + "}";
    }
}

public List<List<Letter>> setLetters() {
    List<List<Letter>> letters = new ArrayList<>();

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('r', 0, 0),
            new Letter('r', 1, 6),
            new Letter('r', 3, 9)));

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('e', 4, 1),
            new Letter('e', 4, 3)));

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('s', 4, 6),
            new Letter('s', 4, 7),
            new Letter('s', 5, 1)));

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('o', 5, 4)));

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('r', 5, 5),
            new Letter('r', 5, 9)));

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('s', 6, 2),
            new Letter('s', 8, 2),
            new Letter('s', 8, 3)));

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('e', 6, 5),
            new Letter('e', 6, 7),
            new Letter('e', 6, 8),
            new Letter('e', 7, 3),
            new Letter('e', 7, 8),
            new Letter('e', 9, 2),
            new Letter('e', 9, 3)));

    letters.add(Arrays.asList(
            new Letter('s', 7, 1),
            new Letter('s', 9, 4)));

    return letters;
}

private void test() {
    List<List<Letter>> letters = setLetters();
    Iterator<List<Letter>> combinations = combinations(letters);
    int count = 0;
    while (combinations.hasNext()) {
        List<Letter> next = combinations.next();
        System.out.println(next);
        count += 1;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

NB: There may be a small problem with this because it thinks there's `1512` combinations.